# Get title from HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I have a server side function which returns content of HTML page:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup

    Meteor.methods({
      sayHello: function() {
        var response = Meteor.http.call("GET", "http://google.com");
        return response;
      }
    });
  });
```

And I have client code where I am trying to get title from this HTML page:

'click .add_tag' : function(e,t) {
      //Session.set('editing_tag_id', e.target.id);

```
  Meteor.call("sayHello", function(err, response) {
    var title = $(response.content).find("title").text();
    var title2 = $(response).find("title").text();
    var title3 = response.content.match(/<title[^>]*>([^<]+)<\/title>/)[1];
    alert(title3);
  });
```

I would like to get jQuery version ('title' or 'title2'), but it doesn't works.  It returns empty string.

'Title3' - version works fine, but I don't like regexps. :)

Is there any way to make 'jQuery'-versions works ?

Comment: I would stick with the regex, even though you don't like it.  There is a huge overhead of constructing a DOM element that is essentially an entire page, purely for the purpose of parsing a small amount of text.  The regex is more lightweight and will perform adequately in slower browsers or on slower machines.

Comment: Hmm... May be you are right.  Can you please add this as answer and I'll accept it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, I will reiterate my comment as an answer...

I would stick with the regex, even though you don't like it. There is a huge overhead of constructing a DOM element that is essentially an entire page, purely for the purpose of parsing a small amount of text. The regex is more lightweight and will perform adequately in slower browsers or on slower machines.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap `response.content` in a `<div>` and then do a selection off of that. This way you have a proper structure to start from rather than an array that you might actually be getting.

```
var $wrap = $("<div></div>").html(response.content);
$wrap.find("title").text();
```

An example of what is probably going on: http://jsfiddle.net/UFtJV/

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget one thing : you should never return HTML to client. You should return Json (or even Xml) that your client will transform into Html using Template.
You are doing like a lot of dev doing Bad Ajax.

Don't forget : "only data on wire, not display".

So there should not be any problem coz, on response you just have to take data from Json formatted response and inject it inside your Template.

Comment: I make a bookmarking service.  I get URL of web site from user and want to store site url and site name to database.  I can not get JSON from any site on the WEB

Comment: Ok i understand coz i also have an application that crawl website. But in fact i parse the web page, build an entity based on parsed info and store it in database. Then i can query the database to return Json from rest service using Meteor methods. You can remove the database part and return Json data.